# date clause function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to get data from table but only from last 1 month and without current week I tried to do that by where clause but i don't know how to exclude current week ( function datepart and getdate doesn't work ) :

| id | date | money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-25 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-10-28 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 3 | 2021-06-25 00:00:00 | 4 |

````
select * 
from table
where DATE(date) > DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), month), INTERVAL 1 month ) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select * 
from table
where DATE(date) >= DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), month), INTERVAL 1 month)
  and DATE(date) <= DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), week), INTERVAL 1 week)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach, less dynamic more on days.

```
WITH sample as (
  SELECT 1 as ID, '2021-11-01' as date, 7 as money
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-11-25',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-11-21',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-11-20',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-11-25',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2021-11-05',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-11-04',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2021-11-01',2
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-10-04',2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2021-10-26',2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2021-10-25',2 
)

SELECT  DATE(date) as date
FROM sample 
WHERE DATE_DIFF(current_date(), DATE(date) , DAY) BETWEEN 7 AND 28
```

or
This which reads a little nicer and probably meets your requirements better.

```
SELECT DATE(date) as date

FROM sample 
WHERE DATE(date) 
    BETWEEN 
      DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 month)
    AND 
      DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK)
```

The last query gives these results,

| Row | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 |
| 2 | 2021-11-21 |
| 3 | 2021-11-20 |
| 4 | 2021-11-05 |
| 5 | 2021-11-04 |
| 6 | 2021-11-01 |
| 7 | 2021-10-26 |